# how to analyze the collision of two photons with four-momentum vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, photons

Q: If two photons with energies $E_1$ and $E_2$ collide, with their trajectories making an angle $\theta$. Is the following right about individual initial 4-momentums and total initial 4-momentum? and how do we find the four-momentum in the center of momentum frame(COM)?

Attempt at Answer:(assuming without loss of generality that particle 1 is moving in + x direction and the whole motion is in x-y plane)
- The initial momentum for each particle is: 
$$p^{\mu}_1=(E_1, E_1,0,0) \\ p^{\mu}_2=(E_2,-E_2cos\theta,E_2sin\theta,0) \\$$
hence the total initial momentum is: $$p^{\mu}_T=(E_1+E_2,E_1-E_2cos\theta,E_2sin\theta,0)$$
- squared length of 4-momentum in lab frame (LBF): $$(p_{T\mu}p^{\mu}_T)_{LBF}=(E_1+E_2)^2- (E_1-E_2cos\theta)^2-(E_2sin\theta)^2=2E_1E_2(1+cos\theta)$$
- square 4-momentum in COM = square length of 4-momentum in LBF:
$$(p_{T\mu}p^{\mu}_T)_{LBF}=(p_{T\mu}p^{\mu}_T)_{COM}=2E_1E_2(1+cos\theta)$$
Now to find the actual momentum in COM I use the above fact that square of the total four momentum is invariant under frame transformation and combining this with the fact that the square of 4-momentum of photon is zero we get:
$$p^{\mu}_{1(COM)}=(E',E'_x,E'_y,0)\\p^{\mu}_{2(COM)}=(E',-E'_x,-E'_y,0)$$
-So the total 4-momentum in COM is:
$$p^{\mu}_{T(COM)}=(2E',0,0,0)$$
squaring it and equating to sqr of total 4-momentum in COM its gives: $$E'^2=\frac{E_1E_2}{2}(1+cos\theta)=E_1E_2cos^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
As I have the magnitude and I know that $$E'^2_x+E'^2_y=E_1E_2cos^2{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
its evident that the two components will have the following form:$$E'_x=\sqrt{E_1E_2}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos{\theta'}\\E'_y=\sqrt{E_1E_2} \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} \sin{\theta'}$$
Question: The way to find the angle $\theta'$ is using Lorentz boost matrix such that the spatial components of four momentum go to zero. Am I right?

Comment: are you sure that photons collide?

Comment: I think its just the inverse of pair annihilation where an electron and a positron come together and create two photons.

Comment: can someone tell me why this question is off-topic? and how can i make it on-topic?